# Javascript regex to split on either ' & ', ' - ' or ' > '

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var category = 'New & improved > crazy - whatever'
```

I'd like to convert it to:

```
var arr = ['New', 'improved', 'crazy', 'whatever']
```

Should work with any combination of `' & ', ' - ' or ' > '` (spaces included).

So far I'm doing:

```
var arr = [];
    if(obj.categories[i].name.indexOf(" > ") >= 0){
        var arr2 = obj.categories[i].name.split(" > ");
        for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i].indexOf(' & ') >=0){
                var newarr = arr[i].split(' & ');
                arr.push(newarr);
            }else{
                arr.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if(obj.categories[i].name.indexOf(" - ") >= 0){
        var arr2 = obj.categories[i].name.split(" - ");
        for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i].indexOf(' & ') >=0){
                var newarr = arr[i].split(' & ');
                arr.push(newarr);
            }else{
                arr.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }else if(obj.categories[i].name.indexOf(" & ") >= 0){
        var arr = obj.categories[i].name.split(" & ");
        return arr;
    }else{
        return [obj.categories[i].name];
    }
```

but this doesn't work if there are both ampersands and dashes in the string. I feel like a regex could handle this much better anyhow, what's the best way to achieve this and make it relatively-futureproof for different use-cases (only involving the above separators, of course)?

Comment: `'New & improved > crazy - whatever'.split(/ [&>-] /)` -- trivial really.

Comment: learning regex will simplify your life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var category = 'New & improved > crazy - whatever';
category.split(/\s*[-&>]\s*/); // => ["New", "improved", "crazy", "whatever"]
```

NOTE: `-` should not be in the middle. Otherwise it is interpreted as character range.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`'New & improved > crazy - whatever'.split(/[>&-]/);`

or without spaces in the result (but result may depend on the formatting of the initial string):
`'New & improved > crazy - whatever'.split(/\s+[>&-]\s+/);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var result = yourstring.split(/[\s>&-]+/);

print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var category = 'New & improved > crazy - whatever'
var arr = category.split(/[\&\>\-]/);
```